# Material UI: how to center vertically TextField and ButtonGroup

Tags: reactjs, forms, grid, material-ui

I'm new to Material UI, and I'm having some trouble vertically aligning the TextField component and the ButtonGroup component.

I tried to play around with the Grid / Grid item but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Here you can see what it looks like:

[image]

The styling:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    root: {
      marginTop: '5px',
    },
    menuButton: {
      color: grey[800],
    },
  }));
```

And the render:

```
    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container className={classes.root}>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <TextField
                        placeholder='Lesson title'
                        label='Title'
                        value={values.title}
                        onChange={handleChange('title')}
                        margin='normal'
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <ButtonGroup variant='contained' aria-label='small contained button group'>
                        <Button><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFile} className={classes.menuButton} /></Button>
                        <Button><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFolderOpen} className={classes.menuButton} /></Button>
                        <Button><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSave} className={classes.menuButton} /></Button>
                        <Button><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} className={classes.menuButton} /></Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Without a jsfiddle (or similar), it's hard to diagnose. If I was to guess, I'd say the tops of these components are aligned. The `TextField` probably has some space built-in for the label to move up on focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use align-items property on the grid container root class:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: '5px',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  menuButton: {
    color: 'grey[800]',
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Grid container alignItems="center" className={classes.root}>` should work too.